# AWS session manager port forwarding in bash script

Tags: linux, aws-ssm

I use AWS Session Manager port forwarding to access a service behind a bastion in my AWS environment. Below is a sample CLI:

```
aws ssm start-session \
          --target $instance_id \
          --region us-east-1 \
          --reason "Remote tunnel to my service" \
          --document-name serviceTunnel
```

NB: I have created document for this.

Now I want to use the same CLI command in a bash script. It means that the script can run bunch of commands on remote host after port forwarding.

The question is how to run the SSM command in background? I have tried using `&`, but it did not help me.

Comment: I found a workaround, adding sleep after establishing SSM session fixed the issue. I don't know, how it worked, but the issue is resolved temporarily. Happy to hear any solution or clarification, thanks again

Comment: Please, add your SSM document content